# How to download files through a HTML page hosted using HTTPListener in a self hosted application

Tags: c#, wpf, httplistener

I have a very simple page hosted in a WPF application using httplistener

```
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Webserver running...");
                try
                {
                    while (_listener.IsListening)
                    {
                        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(c =>
                        {
                            var ctx = c as HttpListenerContext;
                            try
                            {
                                if (ctx == null)
                                {
                                    return;
                                }

                                var requestUrl = ctx.Request.Url.LocalPath.Trim('/');

                                var rstr = _responderMethod(ctx.Request);
                                var buf = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(rstr);
                                ctx.Response.ContentLength64 = buf.Length;
                                ctx.Response.OutputStream.Write(buf, 0, buf.Length);
                            }
                            catch (Exception ex)
                            {
                                // TODO: add log here.
                                Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                            }
                            finally
                            {
                                // Always close the stream. 
                                if (ctx != null)
                                {
                                    ctx.Response.OutputStream.Close();
                                }
                            }
                        }, _listener.GetContext());
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    // TODO: add log here.
                    Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                }
            });
```

And it is hosting this HTML page which should only be able to allow clients to download some local files that were previously generated by the main app.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Self Hosted WebServer</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <h2>
            Downloads
        </h2>
        <ul style="font-size:large">
            <li>
                File 001 (<a href="V1.xlsx" download>xlsx</a> | <a href="v1.pdf" download>pdf</a> | <a href="v1.zip" download>zip</a>)
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

However, when I access the web page and try to download, it wont actually get the local file. I have tried different and absolute path locations but it still isn't able to actually download the file.

Is there something I'm missing, do I really need to process the request somehow instead of having a simple HTML href download link?
Or is there any other hosting way to provide this simple solution?

I'm using VS 2017, C# 4.6.1 and my main app is a WPF.

Comment: You need to make your HTTP listener serve the files.

Comment: Could you provide some code example? About handling/serving the files for a couple links/buttons. Thanks